# Flutter error, Exception caught by rendering library

Tags: flutter, dart, render

my code was working perfectly before and then when I ran flutter upgrade and downloaded the newest version, everytime I try press the button to move to the next page. I get a "Exception caught by rendering library error.

This is the error I get

```
 ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
 Null check operator used on a null value
 The relevant error-causing widget was
 PageView
 lib\menu_frame.dart:59 
 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 E/flutter ( 5787): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Null check 
 operator used on a null value.
```

this is the code I have for that particular page

```
  class MenuFrame extends StatelessWidget {
  PageController pageController = PageController();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Material(
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 28.0, vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.heartBroken,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 48, 111, 1.0),
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'VORTEX',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 38.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 48, 111, 1.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'FITNESS',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 38.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  'Find your passion for fitness!',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                //        SizedBox(
                //        height: 85.0,
                //    ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: PageView(
          controller: pageController,
           //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              HomeSignInWidget(
                goToSignIn: () {
                  pageController.animateTo(1,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
                goToSignUp: () {
                  pageController.animateTo(2,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
              SignIn(),
              CreateLogin(
                cancelBackToHome: () {
                  pageController.animateTo(0,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
          Color.fromRGBO(255, 123, 67, 1.0),
          Color.fromRGBO(245, 50, 111, 1.0),
        ])),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong even though I just upgraded to the newest version??

Comment: If you upgraded the dart sdk version on the pubspec file it should be now using null safety. So you will have go migrate all your code for null safety or you can disable that check if you want not migrate now change the environment lower side to less than 2.12.0. For example (sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the `null safety` update from `Flutter 2.0`

There are 2 solutions to solve this problem

**First**

You will have go migrate all your code for `null safety`

**Second**

Downgrade your sdk enviroment version in `pubspec.yaml`.
Example : `sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"`

You can choose which one you use, if you want to use null safety choose the first one, if you don't want to use null safety choose the second

This will hopefully help you.